# Is it possible to embed an indd file inside another

Tags: adobe-indesign, embed

I know that it is possible to place pages of another indd inside a parent indesign file as a *linked file*. But is it possible to **embed** it? I'm using ID5.5 and the embed option is greyed out for linked indd files, but not for other file types (eg. TIFFs, PDF, etc).

I can understand why it might be unfeasible to embed an indd file, but want to make sure that I'm not missing something obvious.

To clarify my ultimate intention here:

I have a contract template (.indt) that includes my T&Cs at the back. Those T&Cs exist as a separate .indd file, which is 'placed' in the contract .indt. Thus, if my T&Cs get amended/updated the contract template does too.

However, the T&Cs should stop updating in documents *derived* from that template; i.e., once it moves from being a contract template to being a specific contract document, the T&C should get baked in. Hence I want to embed a file that is already in place, subsequent to its initial placement.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it's possible. Did the Content Collector tool appear in 5.5 or 6.0? If it's in 5.5, you could embed the images on the page as you mentioned, group with the rest of the page's contents, add to the Content Conveyer, go to your new InDesign page, place with Content Placer with the "create link" option unchecked.

Comment: Hi SpringKS, thanks for replying. I don't *think* the Content Collector is in 5.5 — I'm not familiar with it and it sounds like something that would replace 'Package' which IS in 5.5. I'm also not familiar with Content Conveyor, so maybe both those things are v6 innovations? (On the other hand, these may just be the official names for tools that I use all the time without really ascribing names to).

Comment: Also, to clarify my ultimate intention here: I have a contract template (.indt) that includes my T&Cs at the back . Those T&Cs exist as a separate indd which is 'placed' in the contract .indt. Thus, if my T&Cs get amended/updated the contract template does too. However, the T&Cs should **stop** updating in documents *derived from* that template. i.e. once it moves from being a contract template to being a specific contract document the T&C should get baked in. Hence I want to embed a file that is already in place, subsequent to its initial placement.

Comment: It looks like I might need to resort to generating an intermediate PDF of the T&Cs document and place that instead, since a PDF *can* subsequently be embedded. It's not as neat, sadly, although I can easily imagine why embedding an indd would be a technical nightmare (conflicts of styles, etc).

Comment: Ah, I see. You want it to update in the first instance to the template file but not in the documents made from that template. Tricky. I think your PDF workaround is a good option. Best of luck!